# Missing Microsoft Graph ServicePrincipal

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

**TL;TR** 
We are creating an AAD application using the Microsoft Graph API. The application has some *requiredResourceAccess* entries where one requires access to microsoft graph. 
After we create the application we want to assign the roles to the service principal using the *appRoleAssignments* object. The object requires the *resourceId* which is the objectId (e. g. of microsoft graph) that I try to determine.

We are using the Graph API itself to get the service principals using: `https://graph.windows.net/<tenant>/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.6` but somehow *Microsoft Graph* is missing:

```
Windows Azure Active Directory      
Microsoft App Access Panel          
Azure Classic Portal                
Microsoft.SMIT                      
Office 365 Configure                
Windows Azure Service Management API
Microsoft.SupportTicketSubmission   
Azure ESTS Service                  
Signup                              
Microsoft password reset service
```

---

**I need to determine the *ObjectId* of the *Microsoft Graph* Service Principal**. Starting with a fresh AAD, it seems like there is no Microsoft Graph Principal:

```
Get-MsolServicePrincipal -AppPrincipalId 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
```

*Output*

```
Get-MsolServicePrincipal : Service principal was not found.
```

How to determine the ObjectId of Microsoft Graph (preferable using the *graph.windows.net* API)?

---

**Edit 1:**

As suggested by Fei Xue, creating the Service Principal via Rest using:

```
POST: https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.6

Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

{
  "appId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "accountEnabled": true
}
```

Gives me a **400** (Bad Request) Error code:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to determine the ObjectId of the Microsoft Graph Service Principal. Starting with a fresh AAD, it seems like there is no Microsoft Graph Principal:

The service principal of multi-tenant app(Microsoft Graph) which register on other tenant will be created after the user grant the consent to the app. This is the reason why you are not able to find it in a fresh tenant.

To get the object id of Microsoft Graph, you need to register an and grant the permission of Microsoft Graph to it like figure below:

[image]

After that the `Get-MsolServicePrincipal` command should works for you(**Note**: you may need to wait a few seconds after you grant the permission).

More detail about the service principal, you can refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent).

### Update

```
POST: https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.6

Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

{
  "appId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "accountEnabled": true
}
```

### Update2

The above REST using the app(`1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2`) which register on Microsoft tenant to acquire the token. To create the service principal for the Microsoft Graph pragmatically, we can call the `New-AzureRMADServicePrincipal` command.

Here is a C# code sample works well for me:

```
try
{
    var userName = "";
    var password = "";
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password)
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }

    // Create Initial Session State for runspace.
    InitialSessionState initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    // Create credential object.
    PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(userName, securePassword);
    // Create command to Log in to Azure.
    Command connectCommand = new Command("Login-AzureRmAccount");
    connectCommand.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("Credential", credential)));
    // Create command to create service principal.
    Command createSP = new Command("New-AzureRMADServicePrincipal");
    createSP.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ApplicationId", "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"));
    using (Runspace psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession))
    {
        // Open runspace.
        psRunSpace.Open();

        //Iterate through each command and executes it.
        foreach (var com in new Command[] { connectCommand, createSP})
        {
            var pipe = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline();
            pipe.Commands.Add(com);
            pipe.Invoke();

        }
        // Close the runspace.
        psRunSpace.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am realy looking for a programmatically solution. Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Based on my understanding, we need to grant the Microsoft Graph manually at least once. After the service principal is created, then you can assign the role via `appRoleAssignments`.

Comment: You are right, after I once grant the permissions for Microsoft Graph manually I am able to retrieve the objectId of the Microsoft Graph Service Principal (and assign the roles via `appRoleAssignments`). If there is no other way, I have to live with that "workaround". Can you confirm that there is no programmatic way?

Comment: We can also create the **service principal** using the Azure AD Graph REST. However it still you need to register an app first. Please let me know if it helps. I also update the post to append to the request for your reference.

Comment: Thanks advanced for the update, that looks promising. I hope I can validate it today and will give you feedback (and accept the answer if its working).

Comment: Found time to test it. Unfortunately I receive a 400 (Bad request) with the message "Specified App Principal ID is Microsoft Internal.". I will add the whole response to the answer.

Comment: @MartinBrandl sorry for the confusion.  I capture this request when I created the service principal using the `New-AzureRMADServicePrincipal` PowerShell command. After the further investigation, it seems this command use an internal app to update the Azure AD. I will update the detailed info for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-MsolServicePrincipal -All | ? {$_.Displayname -match 'graph'} | ft ObjectID,AppprincipalID,DisplayName -AutoSize
```